# Need to evaluate the series $\sum_{i = 0}^n i^5$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need help in evaluating the following sum:

$$\sum_{i = 0}^n i^5 $$

I can evaluate series when they are arithmetic or geometric but I don't know how to solve this one.

Answer (score 3):

**Main Idea:** Knowing the closed form of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^{1},\ldots,\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^{r}$ let's you determine the closed form of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^{r+1}$.

**The Procedure:** We begin with the formula :

$$(k+1)^6-k^6=6 k^5+15 k^4+20 k^3+15 k^2+6 k+1.$$

Writing it for $k=1,\ldots,n$ and adding we obtain :

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
2^6-1^6 &=& 6\cdot 1^5+15\cdot 1^4+20\cdot 1^3+15\cdot 1^2+6\cdot 1+1 \\
3^6-2^6 &=& 6\cdot 2^5+15\cdot 2^4+20\cdot 2^3+15\cdot 2^2+6\cdot 2+1 \\
\cdot &&\\
\cdot &&\\
\cdot &&\\
(n+1)^6-n^6&=&6\cdot n^5+15\cdot n^4+20\cdot n^3+15\cdot n^2+6\cdot n+1 \\ \hline
(n+1)^6-1&=&6[1^5+\cdots+n^5]+15[1^4+\cdots+n^4]+20[1^3+\cdots+n^3]\\&&+15[1^2+\cdots+n^2]+6[1+\cdots+n]+[\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{n\,\rm times}].
\end{array}$$

Knowing that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n1=n,\qquad \sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2},\qquad \sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6},\qquad\\ \sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\dfrac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4},\qquad\sum_{k=1}^nk^4=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30},$$

you can solve for $1^5+\cdots+n^5$, although that is a tedious task.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Use $(r+1)^{m+1}-r^{m+1}=\binom{m+1}1r^m+\binom{m+1}2r^{m-1}+\cdots+\binom{m+1}{m-1}r^2+\binom{m+1}mr+1$

To know $\sum_{r=1}^nr^u,$ set $m=u$

**Assumption** : $\sum_{r=1}^nr^v,0\le v\le u-1$ are known

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) on wikipedia.

Note that even though *finding* the result is difficult, once it has been found is pretty easy to show that it's correct using induction

To answer your question,

$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^5 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2(2n^2+2n-1)}{12}$$